# how to access a mysql database online from a local website?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a database online from a local website, but I got the first error 'connessione fallita'. It isn't a problem of configuration because if I try to use the same code online (it is an inc file) it works! How can i fix it?

```
<?php $connessione=@mysql_connect('ip','username','password');
if (!$connessione){
        echo('connessione fallita');
        exit();
    }
if (!@mysql_select_db('nameofthetable')){
        exit('la selezione database non ha funzionato');
    }
?>
```

Obviously I changed the values of 'ip', 'username', 'password', and table here for security reasons.

Comment: If you have a problem, then don't **suppress** errors! Get rid of those `@`s!

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: what do you mean by _local website_?

Comment: i mean a website running on my computer with xampp

Comment: Check your mysql server accepts remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot.
Try to connect from command line or with a client. Check error returned(not php error message).
most likely it is due to the user not having access from your IP.